# Unable to connect a QPushButton::clicked signal to a slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtwidgets

I'm trying to build a Qt Widget application for learning purposes. I have a class called GBoard implemented as follows:

GBoard.h

```
class GBoard :public QWidget{
public:
    GBoard(QWidget* parent);

private:
    QVector<QPushButton*> butts;
private slots:
    void handleclick(int x);
};
```

GBoard.cpp

```
GBoard::GBoard(QWidget * parent) :QWidget{ parent} {

        QGridLayout* grid = new QGridLayout(this);
        QSignalMapper* mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(" ");

                butts.push_back(button);
                mapper->setMapping(button, butts.size() - 1);;//connects the current button to its index int in butts
                grid->addWidget(button, row, column);
                connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked), mapper , SLOT(map));//From what I understand, map() would emit a signal mapped() that would have the current button's index in butts associated with it
            }
        }
        connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped), this, SLOT(handleclick));
}

void GBoard::handleclick(int x) {
    QPushButton* button = butts[x];
    button->setText(QString("Clicked"));
}
```

However, when this is built and run, the buttons show up as they're supposed to be, but nothing happens when they are clicked. How is one supposed to pass an int argument in the SLOT(handleclick)?

Also, could a lambda expression be used instead of a member function?

Comment: Typo: `connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper , SLOT(map()))`. Better use `connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, mapper, &QSignalMapper::map)`

Comment: make sure your signal and slot use the same data type as a parameter

Comment: @eyllanesc Adding the parentheses leads to the same situation of the buttons not doing anything. And I used the function-to-pointer method before, but it lead to error **C2664** stating: **"cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (_cdecl QAbstractButton::*)(bool)' to 'const char*'"**

Comment: @EnterStrandman What would be the erroneous signal/slot in this case? QPushButton::clicked(bool checked = false) and QSignalMapper::map() are called as is in the [official documentation's example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#map). And the QSignalMapper::mapped() (I did use it with the recommended helper function to deal with its overloadedness) and BGoard::handleclick() both have int as their parameters.

Comment: Please put the Q_OBJECT macro after ```class GBoard :public QWidget{``` so that your class can implement signals/slots mechanism.

Comment: @SaeedSayyadipour I am an absolute idiot. Thank You for your help.

Comment: No, you are surely a clever programmer. Hope my comment has helped you.